The cast to value type 'System.Int32' failed because the materialized value is null LinQ
I do have below query,
 (from p in _dbContext.MyTable
   where batchIds.Contains(p.BatchId)
   select new ParticipantToRespond
    {
       ParticipantId = p.ParticipantId,
       TeamId = (p.TeamId ?? 0),
    }).ToList();`

Which is getting " The cast to value type 'System.Int32' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type." exception for TeamId = (p.TeamId ?? 0)
Here TeamId is int and p.TeamId is int?
I tried below mentioned code change but nothing worked for me
  (p.TeamId.HasValue) ? p.TeamId.Value : 0,
  (p.TeamId ?? 0),
  p.TeamId ?? default(int);
  (int)(p.TeamId ?? 0);
  p.TeamId == null ? 0: p.TeamId.Value
  p.TeamId.GetValueOrDefault

I can not change the type of TeamId in ParticipantToRespond model to int?
This is data specific , facing only when getting p.TeamId as null
Any guidance would be greatly appreciated
Adding more details on request
Here MyTable is DbEntity with int? TeamId
ParticipantToRespond is DTO with int TeamId
Using ORM entity-framework

I suspect the problem is not in your C# or LINQ code, but in your Entity Framework model. You likely have TeamId defined as a nullable int in the database, but is not defined as nullable in your entity framework model. When EF is attempting to construct a MyTable object instance from a row in the database, it is attempting to assign a null TeamId value to a non-nullable TeamId property in the generated MyTable class. This occurs before TeamId is accessed in your LINQ expression.

Please update your question with the appropriate DBMS tag (sql-server, mysql, etc) and ORM tag (entity-framework, entity-framework-core, etc). This will improve visibility for your question and may help others prepare a more specific answer. Adding the relevant parts of your table definition and object model would also help.

My first comment above might be wrong since you stated that "p.TeamId is int?". Looking at other questions containing "failed because the materialized value is null", the fix might be TeamId = ((int?)p.TeamId) ?? 0. However, most of which involve aggregation functions like SUM(), so this might also not apply to your situation.

@TN Thanks for input but it did not work => TeamId = ((int?)p.TeamId) ?? 0

Which EF Core version? It is often used construction for buildng queries and it always works.

This is correct....
Here TeamId defined as a nullable int in the database, but is not defined as nullable in entity framework model. When EF is attempting to construct a MyTable object instance from a row in the database, it is attempting to assign a null TeamId value to a non-nullable TeamId property in the generated MyTable class. This occurs before TeamId is accessed in LINQ expression.
To overcome the issue I did below changes.
First getting all records for DbEntity from DB in memory , then converting to DTO
var participants =  (from p in _dbContext.MyTable
                       where batchIds.Contains(p.BatchId)
                       select new 
                       {
                           ParticipantId = p.ParticipantId,
                           TeamId = p.TeamId
                       }).ToList();
                                    
var participantsWithTeam = participants.Select(p => new ParticipantToRespond
                       {
                           ParticipantId = p.ParticipantId,
                           TeamId = p.TeamId.GetValueOrDefault(), // Default to 0 if null
                        }).ToList();

I hope this is helpful

Why not just fix the entity framework model to correctly mark TeamId as nullable?
